# How to use timeout limit in threads

Tags: ruby, thread-safety, connection-pooling, sequel

I want to run someone sql request at new thread:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mysql2'
require 'sequel'

CONF = {
  adapter: 'mysql2',
  encoding: 'utf8',
  username: 'ruby',
  password: 'ruby',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  pool: 4,
  read_timeout:     10,
  write_timeout:    10,
  connect_timeout:  10,
  pool_timeout:     10,
  database: 'demo',
  max_conns: 7
}

conn = Sequel.connect(CONF)

t = Thread.new { conn['select sleep(100)'].all }
sleep 2

t.kill
sleep 15
```

When I run this code, I expect request will stop after 10 seconds, but it does not. When view mysql process list with:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND != 'Sleep'
```

I see - it is still processing (41 sec):

```
| TIME | QUERY             |  
|------|-------------------|
| 41   | select sleep(100) |
```

How to change my code to get expected result?

Comment: _"How to use timeout limit in threads"_ – does the timeout limit work outside of `Thread.new { ... }`? If not, the problem is a general one and not related to threads.

Answer (score 0):

The `_timeout` parameters are for the TCPSocket used by the client and do not set a maximum wait time for query results.

You could use the `Timeout` from ruby stdlib:

```
t = Thread.new do
  Timeout.timeout(10) do
    Sequel.connect(CONF)['select sleep(100)'].all
  end
end
```

Note: The `Timeout` does have widely known problems as shown [here](https://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/).

You could also consider something like the [connection_pool gem](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool) which has a timeout feature and would do the connection pooling for you.